# How can the forms of my application use different Vcl Styles?

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

How can the forms of my application uses different Vcl Styles?

For example :

form1 -> ruby
form2 -> carbon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`Vcl Styles`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/VCL_Styles_Overview) are Application-wide, so you cannot specify a different Vcl Style by each form.